# VS 2019 Nuget - Project references

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have three projects:

Project A
Project B
Project C

All the projects are in the same solution. Both the projects B and C references the project A by project reference. I don't want to publish a nuget of project A because it doesn't make sense for me.

When I try to pack the projects B and C, the nupkg is not generated and I believe it occurs because the reference.

How do I solve this?

Thanks

André

Comment: Did Project B and Project C not generate the related package B and C? Was there any error message? Besides, could you please share the project type of the three projects, `net standard` or `net framework`? And you need to introduce your question in more detail so that we can troubleshoot it

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to pack the projects B and C, the nupkg is not generated
>   and I believe it occurs because the reference.

I wonder how you pack your project, if Project B and Project C reference the same Project A and then build projects without any errors message,in general, it will not get any problems when you pack these projects.

And if your project A has no other errors, and basically, there are no problems in the process of project packaging.

Or you could follow my guidance；

Please make sure that your projects are based on **Class Library** type.

**----------** If your projects are `Net Framework`

**1)** please make sure that you build your projectS without any errors.

**2)** Net Framework projects can only be packed by `nuget.exe cli` and you shoulld download the nuget.exe from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then configure the path into System Environment Variable **PATH**. And then you can call `nuget` in CMD.

**3)** make sure that there is no Illegal labels and xml nodes in `xxx.nuspec` file and when you use `nuget pack <project-name>.csproj`(cannot use `xxx.sln`) in command line, there is no other errors.

More info about creating a package using the nuget.exe CLI, you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package).

**---------** If your projects are `Net Standard`

**1)** Also, make sure that there are no other build errors. And make sure that you should change the **Output type** to `Class Library`.

**2)** You can use **Pack** UI Button(Right-click on the project-->Pack) or [use dotnet CLI to create a NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli).

**3)** You can also use `nuget.exe` cli to pack new-sdk projects.

**In addition**, if you want to get `A.nupkg` during packing Project B or C, that is not the job for **nuget**.

**Actually**, the content of Project A is under Project B and C which you have reference A in them. And you can get A directly from package B or C. And if you want to get `A.nupkg`, you should pack Project A.

If I misunderstand your issue or there are any detailed key info about this issue, please feel free to let us know.